# Get the topVC or Visible VC and check if a specific VC is in the stack

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

A user adds an item to their bag. As soon as the item is added to the bag, we make a network call to make sure that item is still available.The network call takes a few second to complete in the background.

When an item is added to the cart, it is stored in a singleton that can be accessed from anywhere in the app. Like this:

```
static let shared = Cart()    
var products = [Product]()
```

When the network call returns and the product is unavailable, we remove it from the singleton. This causes an issue if the cart VC was opened during the network call because the table view needs to be reloaded. For that reason, we need to check if the VC that is visible is the cart VC and reload the table view. I would also like to check if the CartVC is in memory and reload the table view. Because if the cart VC is in memory and below another VC then it will also have bad data and when the user closes the VC on top, they will see bad data. How would I do that?

Before this is marked as a duplicate, I did check other posts and none of them work very well. There is also a lot of methods to do this and I would like to know which is best in swift 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the cart is down in the stack make use of `viewWillAppear` and reload the table then. That way you don't reload the table more times than is needed. (If the cart is in the stack and four different network calls come back you only reload the table right before it appears rather than four times when it is hidden.) Table views are often reloaded in `viewWillAppear` specifically to deal with potentially stale data.

For the case when the cart is on screen your singleton can send a notification whenever a product comes back as unavailable and the cart can register for that notification in `viewWillAppear` and deregister in `viewWillDisappear` (or `viewDidDisappear`). The notification could either trigger a complete reload of the data or you could include which product isn't available and let the user know what happened (rather than something suddenly disappearing from the cart with no explanation).

This way the singleton doesn't need to know anything about the cart view controller allowing it to be more reusable.

Comment: why do we need to deregister the notification. This worked but we don't deregister our notifications in any point in the app. Is that really bad? All the notification is doing is telling the VC to reload the table view

Comment: It isn't too bad. By de-registering for the notification when it isn't the visible VC keeps the table view from reloading unnecessarily. If you stay registered for the life of the VC then you don't need to reload the table in `viewWillAppear` but if you ever had lots of items come back as unavailable close to the same time you might see a performance hit as an unseen view is being reloaded over and over. Also make sure the reload call from notifications is happening on the main thread or odd things will happen.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. We were reloading in view will appear anyways so that issue wasn't even a problem. I just didn't realize that. How would we deregister the notification upon viewwilldispapear?

Comment: If the cart VC only has the one notification it listens for you can use the shortcut: `.removeObserver(self)` on the notification center. If there are other notifications you need to keep listening for call `.removeObserver(self, name: notificationName, object: nil)`. Hopefully you are already removing yourself as an observer on `dealloc` or `viewDidUnload`. You can move that code to `viewWillDisappear` (not removing yourself as an observer will lead to a crash down the road when the VC is gone and the notification fires)

Answer (score 1):

You can use notifications to do it. Imagine the case where the item is not available anymore and the VC is open:

1 - Subscribe to a notification like "ItemNotAvailableNotification".

2 - The network call returned and the item is not available anymore.

3 - Post a notification "ItemNotAvailableNotification".

4 - In your VC handle the notification.

Also this approach allows you to handle the "bad data" in your "CartVC" and your "PreviousVC" where the user were lead to believe that the item was available.